# Grafana dashboard for reporting spring integration metrics

Tags: spring-integration, grafana

I have looked at available Grafana dashboards that will visualize metrics for my spring cloud stream app but had no luck. For example my /actuator/prometheus endpoint outputs spring integration metrics of the kind. What out of the box dashboards are available for viewing these metrics?

I am using Prometheus for my Grafana data source.

Spring Integration Metrics from my /actuator/prometheus endpoint

spring_integration_send_seconds_max{exception="none",name="output",result="success",type="channel",} 0.036514698
spring_integration_send_seconds_max{exception="none",name="org.springframework.integration.file.splitter.FileSplitter#0",result="success",type="handler",} 0.04257266
spring_integration_send_seconds_max{exception="none",name="fileSourceFlow.channel#1",result="success",type="channel",} 0.042884163
spring_integration_send_seconds_max{exception="none",name="org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0",result="success",type="handler",} 0.044022164
spring_integration_send_seconds_max{exception="none",name="fileSourceFlow.channel#0",result="success",type="channel",} 0.044374816